# Texmaker: Specifying keyboard shortcuts

Tags: texmaker, keyboard

I like to use the shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> for `^{}` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> for `_{}`.

For some reason, when I enter in the key combos for `^{}`,  Texmaker reads it as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, which works fine. However, for `_{}`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> is interpreted as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>_</kbd>, which doesn't make sense.

It should be like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (as it was in TexStudio) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>_</kbd>, as it had done with the <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>=</kbd> key.

Is there a way to 'type in' the combination, i.e. write in the keyboard combo instead of having the program grab the keys.

I really liked TexStudio for that ability, but it just kept on inserting useless spaces and placeholders for shortcuts.

Comment: I guess you can change using File menu-->`Options`-->`Configure TeXmaker`-->`Shortcuts`--> not to clash with existing ones depending on OS.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bug report for Texmaker.

Comment: This seems to be a bug report, which can only be fixed by the maintainer of the binary so should be reported to him.